# Register a receiver both in the manifest and in the code

Tags: android

I've registered a Power Connection Receiver both in the manifest and in the code.
I wonder what will happen when unregistered it  in the code is it really unregistered  ? 
I know it's not best practice, I just want to know if there is a "real" problem here and what it can cause.

Answer (score 1):

No, nothing will happen with receiver specified in manifest.

Anyway, what logic could be used in order to allow unregister receiver, which registered only at system boot and could receive events even when application is not running? Allowing that, in my opinion, defeats all purpose of those objects.